# JQuery - Search by 2 different Sources

Tags: jquery, html

I have an array and its data shows on a table. I also have date fields and name field for searching.

If I fill all fields, it searches well.  If I fill only date fields and leave the Name field blank, the search still works fine, but if I leave the date fields black and only enter some name in the Name field, it doesn't work even though I have that name in the array.

Please give a hand.  Thanks!  [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/KBMz4/)

HTML

```
<p>From: <input class="datepicker" id="dateFrom" type="text"> To: <input class="datepicker" id="dateTo" type="text"></p>

    Name<input type="text" id="searchByName"><button type="button"  id="searchButton">SEARCH</button><span id="errmsg"></span> 

    <div class="text"></div>
    <table id="myTable" border="1" width="300" cellpadding="5">

    </table>
```

JS

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();

var dateList =[
  {
        name: "Mike Jenson",
        email: "mike_j@yesware.com",
        phone: "9433550193",
        joined: "05/23/2014",
    },
    {
        name: "Jim Stevens",
        email: "jim_s@yesware.com",
        phone: "1299331944",
        joined: "05/22/2014"
    },
    {
        name: "Paul Smith",
        email: "paul_s@yesware.com",
        phone: "4351289654",
        joined: "04/14/2014"
    },
    {
        name: "Sarah Andrews",
        email: "sarah_a@yesware.com",
        phone: "1299332944",
        joined: "03/15/2014"
    },
    {
        name: "Edward O'Brien",
        email: "edward_ob@yesware.com",
        phone: "4782456897",
        joined: "03/27/2014"
    },
    {
        name: "Nicole Plano",
        email: "nicole_p@yesware.com",
        phone: "6657831564",
        joined: "03/30/2013"
    },
    {
        name: "Peter Min",
        email: "peter_m@yesware.com",
        phone: "8893923938",
        joined: "01/07/2013"
    },
    {
        name: "Aaron Jackson",
        email: "aaron_j@yesware.com",
        phone: "6174896315",
        joined: "04/11/2014"
    }
    ];

    $('#searchButton').click(
        function()
            {
                var Namefilter = dateList.filter(
                    function(NameItem)
                    {
                        return  NameItem.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#searchByName').val().toLowerCase()) != -1;
                    });


                var filtered = dateList.filter(function(item){
                    return item.joined >= $('#dateFrom').val() && item.joined <= $('#dateTo').val();
                    });


                refreshTable(Namefilter); 
                refreshTable(filtered);
            }
    );




    function refreshTable(list){
        $("#myTable").html("");
        for (var i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            var tr="<tr>";
            var td1 = "<td>" + list[i]["name"] + "</td>";
            var td2 = "<td>" + list[i]["email"] + "</td>";
            var td3 = "<td>" + list[i]["phone"] + "</td>";
            var td4 = "<td>" + list[i]["joined"] + "</td></tr>";
            $('#myTable').append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4);
        }
        if(list.length==0){
             $('#myTable').html("No Data Found");
        }
    }

    refreshTable(dateList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the fiddle. The reason it didn't work was because of the double `refreshTable()`. The second (the date filter) was overwriting the first (the name filter). As you can see I combined the filters into one. It is now even possible to leave one date field empty and search only for an end date or start date.

http://jsfiddle.net/KBMz4/1/

*The combined filter function:*

```
$('#searchButton').click(
    function()
        {
            var filtered = dateList.filter(
                function(item)
                {
                    return  (item.name == '' || item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#searchByName').val().toLowerCase()) != -1) && 
                        ($('#dateFrom').val() =='' || item.joined >= $('#dateFrom').val()) &&
                        ($('#dateTo').val() == '' || item.joined <= $('#dateTo').val())
                });



            refreshTable(filtered); 
        }
);
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much, JazZro! Before I tried to combine 2 filters, but it didn't work out well.  Then, taking a look at your editing, I see.  Thank you, again!

Comment: You shouldn't compare dates in that format @abcidd, for instance, `"12/15/2001" > "02/23/2015"` returns true. Probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

That is right, the problem is in your filter, but I suggest to you to convert dates for correct comparing like:..

```
            $('#searchButton').click(
                function()
                {
                    var Namefilter = dateList.filter(
                            function(item)
                            {

                                var startDate=new Date($('#dateFrom').val()).getTime();
                                var endDate =new Date($('#dateTo').val()).getTime();
                                var dateJ=new Date(item.joined).getTime();
                                if(dateJ && startDate && dateJ<startDate || endDate && dateJ>endDate) return false;
                                return  item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#searchByName').val().toLowerCase()) != -1;
                            });



                    refreshTable(Namefilter);

                }
        );
```